# can anyone explain the output?

Tags: c++, function

Can anyone explain the output?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;  

int &fun(){   
  static int x = 10;   
  return x;   
} 

int main(){         
  fun() = 30;
  cout << fun();          
  return 0;         
}
```

output is 30

Comment: What do you think it should do? What is unexpected?

Answer (score 11):

That's how static locals work - they persist the value between the function calls. Basically `fun()` has a static local and returns a reference to it, the effect is roughly the same as you would have with a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You return the static by reference, so when you do `fun() = 30` you change it.

It's pretty clear, no?

Basically, `foo()` returns a *reference* to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `fun()`a static variable is created and you return the reference to it. Basically, because of the `static`, the variable is not destroyed even if you exit the scope of the function. You affect the reference with 30 and then recalling the function you get 30 (the x at the second call is exactly the same at the first call). Basically the static works like a global variable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

AS fun is the reference to the function so when you write this line
`fun() = 30;` it stores 30 in its return value i.e `x`, that is why you are getting the output as 30.